# Laravel : Update Stock Value After Order Placement

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

I want to update stock value when order will place. The **challenge** is that the products have different attributes place in the attribute table. [image: Product Attribute Table]

```
Small, Medium, Large, Extra large
```

I want to update the product attribute stock respectively when order is place. For example when user place order user selected products like

```
product_id = 1 size Small quantity is 7
```

So 7 quantity must be **decrement** from the product attribute size **Small** column.

**Checkout**

```
// checkout
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        
        DB::beginTransaction(); 

       
        // Get cart details (Items)
        $cartItems = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray();
        foreach ($cartItems as $key => $item) {
            # code...
            $cartItem = new OrdersProduct;
            $cartItem->order_id = $order_id;
            $cartItem->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            // Get products details
            $getProductDetails = Product::select('product_code', 'product_name', 'product_color')->where('id', $item['product_id'])->first()->toArray();

            $cartItem->product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $cartItem->product_code = $getProductDetails['product_code'];
            $cartItem->product_name = $getProductDetails['product_name'];
            $cartItem->product_color = $getProductDetails['product_color'];
            $cartItem->product_size = $item['size'];
            $getDiscountedAttrPrice = Product::getDiscountedAttrPrice($item['product_id'], $item['size']);

            $cartItem->product_price = $getDiscountedAttrPrice['final_price'];
            $cartItem->product_qty = $item['quantity'];

            $cartItem->save();

            // Want to Update the Product Attribute Table Stock
            $item = new ProductsAttribute;
            $item->where('product_id', '=', $item['product_id'], 'size', '=', $item['size'])->decrement('stock', $request->quantity);
        }

        // Insert Order Id in Session variable for Thanks page
        Session::put('order_id', $order_id);

        DB::commit();

       
    }

}
```

When i run this code it shows me an error

```
InvalidArgumentException
Non-numeric value passed to decrement method.
```

When i enter value directly like decrement('stock', 7) it shows and error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`product_id` is null' at line 1 (SQL: update `products_attributes` set `stock` = `stock` - 7, `products_attributes`.`updated_at` = 2021-05-01 17:18:30 where size `product_id` is null)
```

i search alot but yet not find any solution. Please any one help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the update query and make it simple and clean. The rest of the code is fine.

```
// Want to Update the Product Attribute Table Stock
$product_attribute = ProductsAttribute::where(['product_id' => $item['product_id'], 'size' => $item['size']])->first();
if($product_attribute){
    $stock = $product_attribute->stock - (int) $request->quantity;
    $product_attribute->update(['stock' => $stock]);
}
```

Comment: shahidiqbal it displays an error 
"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException
Add [stock] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\ProductsAttribute]."

Comment: Inside ``ProductsAttribute`` model add ``stock`` to fillable property

Comment: If you still face an issue let me know

Comment: The exception is quite clear that the stock column is not in the fillable

Comment: sir please can you explain in details, how i add stock to fillable array in ProductAttribute Model

Comment: Open productsAttributes model

Comment: Yiu will see there a fillable property. Is it there?

Comment: thanks shahidiqbal i did it but again value is not change in the stock

Comment: Comma separated array

Comment: now the error is remove and also order is complete but the value is not decrease

Comment: Okay can you echo ``$stock`` value

Comment: ooohhh thank you so much shahidiqbal now its working i change the 

$stock = $product_attribute->stock - (int) $item['quantity'];

because i get the values from stock table

Comment: Thanks alot again shahidiqbal for giving precious time

Answer (score 2):

you have to warp it in an array or use two of wheres better and understandable

```
$item->where([
    ['product_id', '=', $item['product_id']],
    ['size', '=', $item['size']],
])->decrement('stock', (int) $request->quantity);
```

Or like this:

```
$item->where('product_id', $item['product_id'])
     ->where('size', $item['size'])
     ->decrement('stock', (int) $request->quantity);
```

Comment: It did't decrement stock value. but working fine. I want to decrement the value of stock which selected by the user like t-shirt with small size quantity 7, so after order is complete the stock value of t-shirt of small size decrease by 7